# To determine if outer join has a match using linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have two tables A and B,which I can outer join with linq. I need a way to find if it is possible to have a boolean along with the query if the outer join has a match. For example, I need a boolean to be true if a record is present in tableA and not in tableB. This can be done in SQL using IF, I was wondering if there was something similar in Linq

```
var result = from a in tableA
             join b in tableB on a.Id equals b.userId into group1
             from g1 in group1.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new{id = g1.Id,userId = g1.userId,boolIsPresent =(present in tableA not in tableB)}.ToList();
```

Comment: by the way that's an inner join not any type of outer join.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you're performing an `inner join`, not a `left outer join`, which means only records/objects that exist in both tables are retrieved. thus your bool `boolIsPresent` would always be *true*.

---

*edit:*

to test if a record is present in *tableA* and does not have a matching record in *tableB* just check if `g1 != null`, i.e:

```
var result = from a in tableA
             join b in tableB on a.Id equals b.userId into group1
             from g1 in group1.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new 
             {
                  id = g1 != null? g1.Id : enterDefault,
                  userId = g1 != null? g1.userId : enterDefault, 
                  boolIsPresent = g1 != null
             }.ToList();
```

Comment: I've never been great with query syntax but I'd be pretty confident that in your select if `boolIsPresent` is false then that means `g1` is null and thus `g1.Id` and `g1.userId` will throw a null reference exception...

Comment: @Chris completely agree with you there, I seem to have forgotten about that, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like

```
boolisPresent = b != null
```

Once you get an Outer join working!